# Is it possible to restore a ClockWorkMod backup to an emulator

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, clockworkmod-recovery, windows, recovery-mode, android-emulator

Is it possible to restore a ClockWorkMod backup to an Android emulator using a PC?

Comment: I'm leaning towards no. A nandroid backup can't be used on a different phone because of the difference in hardware. And since the emulators included in the SDK are going to emulate a specific hardware set, I doubt it would work right.

Comment: You'd have to make the backup *from* the emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can however, try to restore parts of it using [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup).
It allows you to select apps to restore - that way you can get back the data.